# LOGIC LAWS - Logical Problem - Who is older?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

[question in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggHME.png)

I'm having a hard time determining who is older since this was the only statement given. Both answer satisfies the statement.

1. Bill - Sally - Tom
2. Sally - Bill - Tom

I'm not also sure what logical laws I need to use, in order to get the answer.

Comment: I don't see the point to give a picture instead of typing this one-sentence text !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct.  You *cannot* solve this with just that information.

Only knowing that Tom is younger than both Bill and Sally is insufficient to tell whom is the oldest.